# Java 1.5 JPA with Hibernate and H2 is slow to create the EntityManagerFactory

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, h2, java-5

I'm trying to test some of our DB layer in Junit.

The problem I have is that Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory() takes > 200 seconds! Googling for H2, JPA, Hibernate in some combination with createEntityManagerFactory gives nothing useful.

This is my test:

```
import static org.junit.Assert.assertTrue;

import java.util.Date;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.persistence.Persistence;

import org.junit.Test;

public class MinimalSet {
    @Test
    public void TestNamedQuery() {
        Date startTime = new Date();

        EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("TestPersistence");
        EntityManager entityManager = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();

        Date endTime = new Date();

        // Did it take less than 10 seconds?
        assertTrue(((endTime.getTime() - startTime.getTime()) / 1000.0) < 10.0);
    }
}
```

This is my persistence.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="1.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence">
    <persistence-unit name="TestPersistence" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect" />
            <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:h2:mem:test" />
            <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="org.h2.Driver" />
            <property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="root" />
            <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value="" />
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
            <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="false" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

I don't use any other config file (E.g. hibernate.cfg.xml).

I'd appreciate any clue as to why that takes so long.

Thanks.

**UPDATE:**

It has started running fast (<2 seconds).
So I'm thinking there was some event it was waiting for. Does any of this talk to the network?

Comment: You should use `@Test(timeout=10*1000)` for setting the maximum time im ms a test can last. It's much cleaner and safer(because the test migh not end ever) than getting the start and end time and calculating the differrence. Can you try with Eclipselink if it still takes so long ?

Comment: The application under test does not use Eclipselink, so I cannot.

Comment: You're using an old version of Hibernate - not sure which but latest is 4.3.4.Final.  I ran your test with this version and it took .8 seconds (IMO EclipseLink is faster, having found you can create an h2 db with schema and test a small orm in about this time).  Svetlin's first sentence still applies, use timeout.